# PLSQL Extracting Values from a dynamic String

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a String that can have different parameters and different amount of parameters. I am trying to get the parameter name and the parameter value. An example would be:

```
FIRST_PARAM=1^SECOND_PARAM=2^THIRD_PARAM=3^FOURTH_PARAM=4^
```

I am able to get the parameter value through an existing package but it is the name I am having difficulty with. What I did so far is:

```
param_count_ := length(params_) - length(replace(params_,'^',null));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Param Count: '||param_count_);

WHILE(index_ <= param_count_)
LOOP       
    param_value_ := client_sys.Get_Key_Reference_Value(params_,index_);

    IF(index_ = 1) THEN         
        param_name_ := NVL(SUBSTR(params_, 0, INSTR(params_, '=')-1), params_);
    ELSE
        param_name_ := SUBSTR(params_,
                        INSTR(params_, '^',1,index_) + 1,
                        INSTR(params_, '=',1,index_+1) - INSTR(params_, '^',1,index_) - 1);
    END IF;      
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Reference Name: '||param_name_);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Reference Value: '||param_value_);  
    index_ := index_+1;
END LOOP;
```

This results in the below output:

```
Param Count: 4
Reference Name: FIRST_PARAM
Reference Value: 1
Reference Name: THIRD_PARAM
Reference Value: 2
Reference Name: FOURTH_PARAM
Reference Value: 3
Reference Name: 
Reference Value: 4
```

It seems to be out of place by one. How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing your requirement:

```
BEGIN
FOR cur IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(PARAM_, '[^= ]+', 1, 1) AS "KEY",
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR(PARAM_, '[^= ^]+', 1, 2) AS "VALUE"
                 FROM
                (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^\^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) AS PARAM_
                   FROM (SELECT 'FIRST_PARAM=1^SECOND_PARAM=2^THIRD_PARAM=3^FOURTH_PARAM=4^' 
                         AS STR FROM DUAL) T
                CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^\^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
                ))
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Reference Name: '|| cur.KEY ||
    ' <=> '|| 'Reference Value: '|| cur.VALUE);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
Reference Name: FIRST_PARAM <=> Reference Value: 1
Reference Name: SECOND_PARAM <=> Reference Value: 2
Reference Name: THIRD_PARAM <=> Reference Value: 3
Reference Name: FOURTH_PARAM <=> Reference Value: 4
```